# Performance test between debug & release mode

Tags: debugging, release

I'm testing performance. The program receive huge bytes from other other side through TCP connection and parse into target structure.

If I try it in Debug (F5), delayed very seriously. But if I try it in Release (Ctrl+F5), it works very smoothly.
I check the situation using WireShark, TCP window update statement let me know the status of receive side.

I wonder if I want to make end-user program. The program should be work in debug mode as well as  release mode?

The data size really big and the transmit interval is very short. In this case, the difference of performance between debug and release will be very cleary? I couldn't see that kind of difference ever.

Comment: Performance testing "Debug" builds is quite worthless. If your app runs as expected in "Release" mode, then everything is fine. No need to lose sleep over it. **Never** deploy the "Debug" version to clients.

Answer (score 1):

This question conflates two different issues. One is Debug versus Release builds. Debug builds are slower for numerous reasons, all aimed at making debugging easier.

The second issue is that launching an application under the debugger (F5) versus not under the debugger (Ctrl+F5) can affect performance. The Windows heap does additional checks when launched under the debugger, processing of OutputDebugString and module loads may take longer, etc.

These two issues are completely orthogonal. You can launch a Release build under the debugger, or you can launch a Debug build not under the debugger.

If the problem is that Debug builds are slower then, well, yes, they are. You can control this somewhat by enabling optimizations in some source files or by turning off debug iterators, but Debug builds are supposed to be somewhat slower.

If the problem is that builds launched under the debugger are slower then don't do that when you care about performance. You can always attach the debugger after, which will avoid some of the slowdown, or don't attach the debugger at all.

Answer (score 0):

When you publish, your application, it should be compiled in "Release" mode only. Debug mode is used to really "debug" while your development.

Answer (score 0):

You should only program with Release mode in mind. It's really the only version of your app that should reach the end-user. Debug mode is only for "housekeeping" and well... debugging. Not really the user's concern.

Comment: You should only *profile* in release mode. You should use your Debug build as much as possible because it should contain asserts and other error checking that help ensure that your code is correct.